# Scope of System.Variants.NullStrictConvert

Tags: delphi, null, variant

In a VCL application tt avoid

```
Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (OleStr)
```

errors and because i want that Null variants

> to be automatically converted to empty strings, 0 integers, or false
>   booleans

(as specified in one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224959/could-not-convert-variant-of-type-null-into-type-olestr))

i set

```
uses System.Variants

//[...]

NullStrictConvert  := False;
```

Is it ok to do this in the `OnCreate` method of the main datamodule of a VCL app? Is this setting global? I can't find this info in the [official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Variants.NullStrictConvert).

From testing it seems that setting it once it is enough, but i'd like to have an extra reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This variable is defined at module scope and so has global impact. If you modify the variable, then all code in your module that executes subsequently will be affected.

The intention would be that you set the value once at module initialization and then leave it unchanged. Yes you can do that in a data module `OnCreate`, but personally I would make the change in a unit `initialization` block.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will use initialization as advised by you.